# how to add author to post-commit in SVN using commit-notification

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, post-commit

I am using commit-notification command in post-commit hook, it works fine but the email dosn't contain the author for the commits. Here is my script:

```
"<visualsvnpath>\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
commit-notification "%1" -r %2 ^
--from myemail.com --to anothermail.com ^
--smtp-server smtpserver ^
--smtp-port 25 ^
--smtp-user someone@company.com ^
--smtp-password password
```

Is there any way to add author in the mail notification?

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2013? Please, upvote it then. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E-mail notifications sent with VisualSVNServerHooks.exe specify username of a committer in a "From:" field.

E.g. if the committer's account username is John.Doe and you send notifications from noreply@domain.com the received notification's "From:" will look like:

`John.Doe <noreply@domain.com>`.